# Swift 3 background Image Or Gif

Tags: ios, image, swift3, background-image, animated-gif

So I've looked around this question for months always hearing make it the screen sizes of the phone it self, If I want a background image or gif to be in my application so it fits the whole size of the screen and can be used on different device sizes. Is there a a default size I should use so it doesn't make the image or gif look stretched out or crunched up? Or do I go about making different size images for each single device size and implementing a method that states what images to used based on the device the application is on?

Comment: If you are using `UIImageView`, it has `contentMode` so you can avoid image stretched.

Comment: is there a certain pixel by pixel measurement i should use to make it look the same on all devices? @Ryan

Comment: Use fixed ratio UIImageView and set contentMode .aspectXXX